# BehaviorSubject Services for components interaction - Property used before its initialized

Tags: angular

I want to use form data from one component to another, in first component I'm using `(ngModel)` and with `BehaviorSubject` I'm storing my data in `services`.

Now, I'm `subscribing` to those services in another component and getting data in local variables. Till here, it's working fine and I'm able to get the data but only when I put that values in Model it says `Property 'someName' is used before its initialization.ts(2729)`

I want to put this data in Model and call an post API based on this, what is the right way to do?

Comment: please provide the code you have tried

Comment: can you share your code, please, to helps your